# How to find rank based on two values in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a workout related web application in php which contains workout table that stores daily workout data of users based on activity type like(Run, Swim, Cycling etc.). I need to generate a leaderboard based on ranking system based on high.

[Default workout table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3dLN.png)

[image]

```sql
SELECT 
  SUM(avg_speed) AS average_speed, 
  SUM(max_speed) AS maximum_speed, 
  date_created, 
  user_id 
FROM workouts 
WHERE date_created LIKE '%2019-12%' 
GROUP BY user_id
```

With this query I am getting output as below:

[output after running select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztPVE.png)

[image]

My required output should be based on average_speed<30 and maximum_speed<50. I am not able to write the logic for getting the ranks. and also if two users having same points rank should come as 1 1 3.

Comment: 1) You obtain random `date_created` from all possible for each `user_id` . 2) *required output should be based on average_speed<30 and maximum_speed<50* Use `HAVING`.

Comment: yes, because for a particular  month i need to get data

Comment: You must get a specific date. For example, `MIN(date_created)`.

Comment: consider my date_created is 2019-12, so  i need to generate rank for the month of december only based on min and max speed

Answer (score 2):

You can try this SQL statement:

```
SELECT s1.avg_speed, s1.max_speed, s1.user_id,
       @row_num:=IF(s1.avg_speed = @last_avg_speed, @row_num, @origin_row_num+1) rank_no,
       @last_avg_speed:=s1.avg_speed last_avg_speed,
       @origin_row_num:=@origin_row_num+1 origin_row_num
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(avg_speed) avg_speed, SUM(max_speed) max_speed, user_id FROM workouts
        WHERE date_created LIKE '2019-12%'
        GROUP BY user_id
) s1, (SELECT @origin_row_num:=0, @row_num:=0, @last_avg_speed:=0) R
WHERE s1.avg_speed < 30 AND s1.max_speed < 50
ORDER BY s1.avg_speed DESC
```

Here is my test code:

```
create table workouts
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id int not null,
    date_created date null,
    activity_type varchar(10) null,
    avg_speed float null,
    max_speed float null
);
DELETE FROM workouts WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3)
INSERT INTO workouts (id, user_id, date_created, activity_type, avg_speed, max_speed)
VALUES (NULL, 1, '2019-12-01', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 1, '2019-12-02', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 1, '2019-12-03', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 1, '2019-12-04', 'Walk', 1, 10),

       (NULL, 2, '2019-12-01', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 2, '2019-12-02', 'Walk', 5, 10),
       (NULL, 2, '2019-12-03', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 2, '2019-12-04', 'Walk', 1, 10),

       (NULL, 3, '2019-12-01', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 3, '2019-12-02', 'Walk', 5, 10),
       (NULL, 3, '2019-12-03', 'Walk', 1, 10),
       (NULL, 3, '2019-12-04', 'Walk', 1, 10);

SELECT s1.avg_speed, s1.max_speed, s1.user_id,
       @row_num:=IF(s1.avg_speed = @last_avg_speed, @row_num, @origin_row_num+1) rank_no,
       @last_avg_speed:=s1.avg_speed last_avg_speed,
       @origin_row_num:=@origin_row_num+1 origin_row_num
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(avg_speed) avg_speed, SUM(max_speed) max_speed, user_id FROM workouts
        WHERE date_created LIKE '2019-12%'
        GROUP BY user_id
) s1, (SELECT @origin_row_num:=0, @row_num:=0, @last_avg_speed:=0) R
WHERE s1.avg_speed < 30 AND s1.max_speed < 50
ORDER BY s1.avg_speed DESC
```

The output:

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
|avg_speed|max_speed|user_id|rank_no|last_avg_speed|
|--------------------------------------------------|
|8        |40       |2      |1      |8             |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|8        |40       |3      |1      |8             |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|4        |40       |1      |3      |4             |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

in the last column `last_avg_speed` is always equal to avg_speed, you can ignore it.

By the way, if you are using MySQL 8.0.0 or later, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()` function to resolve it very very simply. And [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) is the docs.

Comment: thanks...this code is working as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play querying like this.

```
select user_id,avg,max from users nu
join
(
    select sum(avg_speed) as avg,sum(max_speed) as max,user_id FROM workouts group by user_id
)t2 on t2.user_id=nu.id 
 where avg<30 and max <50
 and date_created LIKE '%2019-12%'
group by t2.user_id order by avg desc;
```

loop this result in your php code to add your ranking logic like below example. (Below logic and code is not tested).

```
$rank=0;
$same_rank=0;
foreach($workouts as $key=>$item)
{
 $avg=$item->avg;
 if($avg!=$prev_item)
 { 
    $add_rank=$same_rank!=0?$same_rank:1;
    $rank=$rank+$add_rank;
    $same_rank=0;
 }
 else
 {
  $same_rank++; //increments if same value repeated
 }

 $workouts[$key]['rank']=$rank;
 $prev_item=$avg;


 }
echo $workouts;
```

This may help you